# Outlets in UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, outlet

I have loaded a viewController's view to an other viewController's view in Swift.

```
let myCustomView = MyCustomView()

let myView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("xibView", owner: myCustomView, options: nil)[0] as UIView

self.view.addSubview(myView)
```

When I have tried to add an UITableView to my MyCustomViewController (.xib), it works. But, if I add outlets like "DataSource"/"Delegate" or an action on a button : the application crashed.

Regards

Comment: Have you implemented `DataSource`/`Delegate` methods?

Comment: Yes, I have implemented DataSource/Delegate. For example, when I tried to add an action on a button : the application crashed too. The issue is generalised to Outlets.

Comment: Show your `IBAction` handlers, please

Comment: [Handler](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4YLG3I-U2SLSEVNYXZQSUxhbTQ/view?usp=sharing) and [Code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4YLG3I-U2SLUXZLZjlqR2VvdEk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: If you destroy that `IBAction` all works fine?

Comment: Yes. I can create an Outlet (Button, TableView) but as soon as I attempt to implement an Action to a Button or Delegate/DataSource to a TableView : it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you distinguish which connection exactly breaks your app? `DataSource`, `Delegate` or `IBAction`?

Comment: All. Even if there is only an IBAction, my app crash. I obtain this error message : [Crash](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4YLG3I-U2SLXzdhb1lUZ2tsUms/view?usp=sharing) It's not really explicit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29134921/ios-load-xib-with-associated-vc-inside-uiview : the same situation

Comment: Try to make `myCustomView` as instance variable in your `viewController`

Comment: Yes, I have tried : "let MyCustomView = MyCustomView.sharedInstance()" and I've got always a crash in app delegate EXEC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: Is `sharedInstance` a singletone?

Comment: Yes, It is a singleton.

Comment: Please check my answer if it is works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try different approach to load a `UIView` from `xib`

```
let namedNib = UINib(nibName: "xibView", bundle: nil)
let aNib = namedNib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)
let myView = aNib.first as UIView
self.view.addSubview(myView)
```

Comment: I have this error message ```*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't add self as subview'``` The view don't load. If I remplace "self" by an instance variable in your viewController (.xib), I've got again a crash in app delegate EXEC_BAD_ACCESS.  Sorry, I don't succeed to fix this bug.

Comment: What do you get if compare `myView` and `self.view`? Are they equal?

Comment: No, they aren't equal.

Comment: Could you try to load that `view` in another `viewController`?

Comment: Does your first `viewController`'s view `viewController` retained anywhere?

Comment: No, it didn't retained anywhere.

Comment: Try to retain it, please

Comment: ``// Add to the view hierarchy (thus retain). self.view.addSubview(myView)``It's the one place where it retained. ```Because, this xib is designed for one-time use only.

Comment: You add only its `view`, not `viewController`

Comment: Okay ! It works, I understood ^^° Thank you very much ! It's really cool to help me.